# magento 2 how to set base or thumbnail image to product

Tags: magento2

My question was after yopu add a image to te prodcut in magento 2, how to set is as the default image (base image) for the product.
I found out how to add images to the product, but coulnd find a was to set it as base image for the product.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

after loading the product:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(PRODUCT ID);
```

You can get all the images of a product with the following code:

```
$images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
```

This will return a collection with all the images added to the product.
You can pick any image or take the first one like this:

```
$image = $images->getFirstItem();
```

After that you van get the image url with

```
$imageUrl = $image->getFile();
```

To set it to the product is this:

```
$product->setImage($image);
$product->setSmallImage($image);
$product->setThumbnail($image);
$product->setSwatchImage($image);
```

And save the product like this:

```
$product->save();
```

Comment: Hmm, it's always mentioned everywhere that `$product->save()` is deprecated in Magento 2. Does anybody know how to do this in a way that doesn't clash with M2 recommended use?

Comment: @BigSmoke The recommended way is to save from the ProductRepository, which takes the whole product as the parameter: `$this->productRepository->save($product);` It is explained in Key Shang's answer below

Answer (score 3):

After get the product ids you want, for each product write the codes like below

```
$product = $this->productRepository->getById($data['product_id']);
$mediaGalleryEntriesTemp = [];
$i = 1;
foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryEntries() as $item) {
    if ($i === 1) {
        $item->setTypes(['image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail']);
    }
    $mediaGalleryEntriesTemp[] = $item;
    $i++;
}
$product->setMediaGalleryEntries($mediaGalleryEntriesTemp);
$this->productRepository->save($product);
```

> Notice: '**swatch_image**' role only available in simple product or
>   configurable child product, not **configurable parent** product.

After my test, the solutions work in Magento 2.2.3, other version should work too.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for Magento 2.3.3 and working fine

for me, my scenario is a little bit different I need the base and small image for my existing products and I have images name :)

After saving the image you can use this code to make the base image.

```
    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product->getId());
    $images = $product->getMediaGalleryEntries();
    $mediaGallery = $product->getMediaGallery();
    //if there are images
    if (isset($mediaGallery['images'])){
        //loop through the images
        foreach ($mediaGallery['images'] as $image){        
            // make the base image by name         
            if(strpos($image['file'], 'PRODUCT_NAME') !== false){
                $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action')->updateAttributes(array($product->getId()), array('image'=>$image['file'], 'small_image'=>$image['file']), 0);
                //stop
                break;
            } else{
                echo "can't find";
            }        
        }
    }
```

Change the PRODUCT_NAME or if no need it removes the if-else condition

I hope it helps other